# 配列の中にあるオブジェクトの参照の仕方

Tags: ruby

```
temp = [
  {
    :hoge => 1,
    :huga => []
  },
  {
    :hoge => 2,
    :huga => []
  },
]
```

この配列の「`hoge`が`1`のオブジェクトを参照する」方法はありますか？

イメージとしては以下のような操作を行いたいです。

```
temp[{:hoge == 2}][:huga] << 123
```

↓

```
[
  {
    :hoge => 1,
    :huga => []
  },
  {
    :hoge => 2,
    :huga => [123]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Enumerable#find` を使って次のようにできます:

```
temp.find{|h| h[:hoge] == 1}[:huga] << 123
```